# Dafny: types with contraints

Tags: dafny

I am trying some things in Dafny. I want to code a simple datastructure that holds an uncompressed image in memory:

```
datatype image' = image(width: int, height: int, data: array<byte>)
newtype byte = b: int | 0 <= b <= 255
```

Actually using it:

```
method Main() {
  var dat := [1,2,3];
  var im := image(1, 3, dat);
}

datatype image' = image(width: int, height: int, data: array<byte>)
newtype byte = b: int | 0 <= b <= 255
```

leads Dafny to complain:

> stdin.dfy(3,24): Error: incorrect type of datatype constructor argument (found seq, expected array)
>   1 resolution/type errors detected in stdin.dfy

I might also want to demand that the byte array is not null, and the size of the byte array is equal to width * height * 3 (to store three bytes representing the RGB value of that pixel).

What way should I enforce this? I looked into newtype, which lets you put some constraints on variables with a certain type, but this works only for numeric types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dafny supports both immutable sequences (which are like mathematical sequences of elements) and mutable arrays (which are, like in C and Java, pointers to elements).  The error you're getting is telling you that you're calling the `image` constructor with a `seq<byte>` value where an `array<byte>` value is expected.

You can fix the problem by replacing your definition of `dat` with:

```
var dat := new byte[3];
dat[0], dat[1], dat[2] := 1, 2, 3;
```

However, the more typical thing, if you're using a datatype (which is immutable), would be to use a sequence.  So, you probably want to instead change your definition of `image` to:

```
datatype image = image(width: int, height: int, data: seq<byte>)
```

Btw, note that Dafny allows you to name a type and one of its constructors the same, so there's no reason to name one of them with a prime (unless you want to, of course).

Another matter of style is to use a half-open interval in your definition of `byte`:

```
newtype byte = b: int | 0 <= b < 256
```

Since half-open intervals are prevalent in computer science, Dafny's syntax favors them.  For example, for a sequence `s`, the expression `s[52..57]` denotes a subsequence of `s` of length 5 (that is, 57 minus 52) starting in `s` at index 52.  One more thing, you can also leave out the type `int` of `b` if you want, since Dafny will infer it:

```
newtype byte = b | 0 <= b < 256
```

You also asked about the possibility of adding a type constraint, so that the sequence in your datatype will always be of length 3.  As you discovered, you cannot do this with a `newtype`, because `newtype` (at least for now) only works with numeric types.  You can (almost) use a subset type, however.  This would be done as follows:

```
type triple = s: seq<byte> | |s| == 3
```

(In this example, the first vertical bar is like the one in the `newtype` declaration and says "such that", whereas the next two denote the length operator on sequences.)  The trouble with this declaration is that types must be nonempty and Dafny isn't convinced that there are any values that satisfy the constraint of `triple`.  Well, Dafny is not trying very hard.  The plan is to add a `witness` clause to the `type` (and `newtype`) declaration, so that a programmer can show Dafny a value that belongs to the `triple` type.  However, this support is waiting for some implementation changes that will allow customized initial values, so you cannot use this constraint at this time.

Not that you want it here, but Dafny would let you give a weaker constraint that admits the empty sequence:

```
type triple = s: seq<byte> | |s| <= 3
```

So, instead, if you want to talk about that an `image` value has a `data` component of length 3, then introduce a predicate:

```
predicate GoodImage(img: image)
{
  |img.data| == 3
}
```

and use this predicate in specifications like pre- and postconditions.

Program safely,

Rustan